# Может ли язык влиять на формирование стереотипного, «бытового» уровня мышления?

Tags: психолингвистика

И каким образом язык влияет на формирование стереотипного, "бытового" мышления?

Answer (score 2):

Ваш вопрос слишком общий для формата справки. Могу посоветовать Вам посмотреть статью в Википедии про [Гипотезу лингвистической относительности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8). Ещё более популярное изложение можно найти в замечательной книге Гая Дойчера "Сквозь зеркало языка".

Если в двух словах, могу предложить такой ответ: вряд ли язык может формировать мышление какого-либо уровня, но возможность существования корреляции между языком и мышлением допускается некоторыми учёными.